# How to check if user input a string value?

Tags: c

So here's my code:

```
main()
{
        char *iochar;                                                                                   

        printf(" Enter a standard line: ");                                                             
        scanf ( "%s", &iochar);

        if (iochar != NULL)
        {
                printf(" Here's what you entered: %s ", &iochar);
        }
        else
        {
                printf(" Oops! Looks like you forgot to enter something! ");
        }
}
```

My problem is that I can scan the user entry and store it and if something exists it puts out the correct message. But if I just hit return to test for no input (null, empty, etc) the program neither quits nor outputs my error message. It just hangs until I input something.

I've been programming in Java for the last two semesters so C is totally lost on me right now. So any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: so you just want to validate whether input is a string or not?

Comment: Don't use `scanf` (ever).  Use `fgets`, or, if you have it, `getline`.  Then "just hitting return" will produce the string `"\n"` and typing control-D (which forces an EOF condition) will produce the string `""`.  Incidentally, the spaces at the ends of your second and third `printf` strings should be `\n` instead.

Comment: @OusmaneDiaw At this point, yes. My code has to do other things, but I have to be able to validate that there is in fact some sort of input.

Comment: Where to begin? No memory allocation for `char *iochar;`. Not checking the function return value from `scanf`. Using `&` for string arguments to `scanf` and `printf`... I suggest the man pages for functions you use, and enabling full compiler warnings.

Comment: @WeatherVane Well.... that's how my teacher told us we should do it, and how he does it in his examples... so....

Comment: Does your teacher also recommed `main()` just like that? Send him/her on a course of "continuing education". Tactfully.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yep. Pretty much.

Comment: The `%s` conversion specification for `scanf()` skips white space, including newlines and blanks and tabs, and doesn't start saving anything until it comes across a non-white-space character.  If you care about newlines, you can't use `scanf()` because it doesn't care about newlines (unless you work *very* hard — so hard that it isn't worth doing).  If you care about lines, use a line-based input function (e.g. `fgets()`) and then maybe `sscanf()` to parse the line that it reads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scanf ( "%s", &iochar);` is not useful for detecting an empty line.

`"%s"` first directs `scanf()` to read and discard all leading white-space, including `'\n'` before proceeding to read non-white-space characters. So code has lost the `'\n'`.

---

Instead use `fgets()`

```
// Enough room for 80 characters + \n + \0
#define LINE_SIZE (80 + 1 + 1)
char buf[LINE_SIZE];

if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) {
  puts("end-of-file or input error detected");
} else if (buf[0] == '\n') {
  puts("Empty line entered");
} else {
  printf("Input line: <%s>\n", buf);
}
```

Input

```
Hello World (and <Enter>)
```

Output (Note the \n read in is still retained)

```
Input line: <Hello World
>
```

---

To be clear: In C, a *string* is a sequence of characters up to and including a terminating *null character* `'\0'`.  Users do not enter *strings*.  User input is usually a *line* of text up to and including a terminating *line feed* `'\n'`.  `fgets()` reads a *line* of input and then appends a *null character* to the resultant `buffer` is a *string*`.

Comment: Oh my gosh thanks so much! It works like a dream now! Haha.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my advice: Don't use `scanf`. Its rules are confusing, and it's very difficult to get the behaviour you want.
Instead, I recommend you use `getch` to manually read each character into a buffer until the user enters a newline character `'\n'`. Then you can zero terminate the buffer with a `0`, and then use the buffer as a normal string. For it to be empty, just check the length of the string with `strlen(x)`.

Comment: You know of `fgets`?

Comment: Yes, but I prefer to not use standard library functions that I can implement myself.